# Working with Java ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, python, runtime, processbuilder

This is wat i'm trying to do, read input, output streams from python to java using class 'ProcessBuilder'. For this I have written a sample java, sample python script,

**Sample.java**

```
String[] args = new String[]{"python","Sample.py"};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
try {
   p = builder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

StreamWriter stdInput = new StreamWriter(p.getInputStream());
stdInput.start();

... 

private class StreamWriter extends Thread{
... 
   public void run(){
      try {
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
         int ch;
         synchronized (StreamWriter.class){
            while ( (ch = br.read()) != -1){
               System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
          }
       }
       catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();  
       }
    }
 }
```

**Sample.py**

```
print('First line')
print('Second line')
intput1_var = raw_input("Enter first value")
print('you entered '+input1_var)

input2_var = raw_input("Enter second value")
print('you entered '+input2_var)
```

I tested my code on both Ubuntu & Windows8, Below is the result

In Windows8 I was able to print 'First line', 'Second line' 'Enter first value' and waits for input from the user. The question here is, how do I input data to script, using process.getOutputStream(), becuase once i write bufferedWriter.write("Something"), bufferedWriter.flush(), until i call outputstream.close() in my code ( which will close the output stream for the process, without which i cannot give the second input to the script) , it's not printing 'Enter second value' to ask user for the second value.

In Ubuntu, I was not even getting any output from the beginning ( I was expecting atleast the program print's out until 'Enter first value' but nothing usual), the program keeps waiting for the input

Any help on this

Comment: On a side note: You are aware of Jython? http://www.jython.org/

Comment: yes, i'm aware, but i couldn't figure out how to stream input, output, error from python script to java using loose coupling b/w java & python, i.e. assuming python script written is a black box (u can pass arguments to script's, that ok) to java sample code ?